# IF Excel Formula

Tags: worksheet-function

Can somebody help me with This Formula?
I need to set up the IF Function in Excel which states: If the difference between C3 and D3 is between -5 and 5 to say OK if not say ERROR, Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

use ABS():

```
=IF(ABS(C3-D3)<=5,"OK","ERROR")
```